# Primefaces lazy datatable : how to retrieve the visible list

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a lazydatatable displaying thousands of cars. I ll have a buy button on the top of the page.
Basically, i want the user to buy all the cars visibles on the list when I press on the Buy Button. I m struggling to get a list limited to these cars.

How can I do?

xhtml

```
 <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carView.listCars}" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink}
 {LastPageLink}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" selection="#{carView.selectedCar}" id="carTable" lazy="true">
     <p:column headerText="Year">
     <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Brand">
         <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
     </p:column>
```

CarService

```
public void buy{

...
}
```

CarView

```
public void init(){
    LazyCarDataModel cars= restService.getCars();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `p:datatable` in lazy mode, **you** provide the data for the 'visible' list via the `load` method in your LazyDataModel. So if you keep that list in one way or another on the server (e.g. storing it in a `@Viewscoped` bean`), it is available when you click 'buy'.

Another way is to support multiple selection and have a 'select all' toggle box at the top of the selection. And then use the selected files server side